# Can A2C deal with a reward that is decided later than action selection?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, policy-gradients, advantage-actor-critic

I am trying to use a policy gradient based RL algorithm, A2C. However, my training case is slightly different from what typical training tragets are. In my case, a reward is given not immediately after an action is selected, but after some intervals in possibly different order.

For example, in general

```
for epoch in epochs:
  state = agent.get_current_state()
  action = agent.get_action(state)
  reward, next_state = env.evaluate(state, action)
  step += 1
  if step == optimization_interval:
    optimize_model(state, next_state, action, reward, ..)
    step = 0
```

Let's assume that I want to train mapping jobs to proper machines in cloud system.

```
for epoch in epochs:
  while all_job_done:
    for job in mappable_jobs:
      job_specific_state = agent.get_current_state(job)
      machine = agent.get_action(job_specific_state)
      state_list.apppend(job_specific_state)
      action_list.append(machine)
    for job in runnable_jobs: // Mappable jobs can be runnable in random order
      reward = env.evaluate(agent.get_state(job), agent.get_action(job))
      step += 1
      if step == optimization_interval:
        optimize_modeL(get_state(job), get_action(job), reward, ..)
        step = 0
```

Let's assume that mappable_jobs contained job1, job3, job5 at the first step (not epoch, but one iteration of the while loop), and job 2 at the second step.
Let's assume that its optimization interval is 1.
Let's assume that job 2 was immediately runnable, and optimized the model before job 1 is evaluated. Then the model when job 1's action is decided is different from the one when job 1 is evaluated. And so, it cannot optimize the model correctly.
So I am concluding that A2C cannot be used, but I may use DQN-like models that optimize the model with random states.

My question might be silly as I am a novice on RL, but is this correct?

Comment: what DQN can achieve, A2C can too, given enough time, so if your problem is with the RL formulation, i suggest you to search in the literature "delayed reward RL" and use one of the proposed approaches